# Boostrap offcanvas interact with background

Tags: bootstrap-5

I'd like to have a Bootstrap Offcanvas displayed, and still be able to interact with the rest of the page without getting the Offcanvas closed. Is this possible? None of these examples address that: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/offcanvas/.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an offcanvas with a [static backdrop](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/offcanvas/#static-backdrop) and add this CSS rule to hide the backdrop :

```css
.offcanvas-backdrop {
  display: none;
}
```

```css
.offcanvas-backdrop {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop" aria-controls="staticBackdrop">
  Toggle static offcanvas
</button>
<button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" onclick="alert('clicked!')">You should not be able to click me</button>
</div>

<div class="offcanvas offcanvas-start" data-bs-backdrop="static" tabindex="-1" id="staticBackdrop" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel">
  <div class="offcanvas-header">
    <h5 class="offcanvas-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Offcanvas</h5>
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
  </div>
  <div class="offcanvas-body">
    <div>
      I will not close if you click outside of me.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```